# vim - Delete to the end from Searched word

Tags: vim

I would like to remain the only the first pattern (The "Important#") in the text.

```
Input: 
Im port ant1 RandomJunk
Imp ortan t4 Lorum ipsum
Imp ort ant5 dolor sit amet, conse
I mport ant3 Aliquam vel nibh diam
Impo rtant 1 dignissim vel nisi vitae
Imp orta nt9 dui ut posuere rhoncu
```

```
Output: 
Im port ant1
Imp ortan t4
Imp ort ant5
I mport ant3
Impo rtant 1
Imp orta nt9
```

New to vim and don't really understand :%s or :s
Please help

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Are you sure that there must be three words at the beginning of each line? or are you sure that there must be a number at the end of `Important`?

Comment: use <C-n> and select horizontal line and delete lines

Comment: @romainl I had really no idea on vim, only idea is manually delete line by line

Comment: @Yves Ans for all those questions are yes.

Comment: @ycohui Then execute `:%s/.*\d\zs.*//g`. `.*` is to match anything and `\zs` is to mark the beginning of the matching area. So this cmd means: for each line, find a digit and use it but exclude it as the beginning of the matching area and match anything to the end. Replace the matching area with nothing.

Comment: If you have no idea how to do such things in Vim, then why use it in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have to delete everything after 12th character on each line
you can use vim's search and replace:

Overall command structure:
`:s/searchThis/replaceWithThis`

This is a command to do the job:
`:%s/\(.\{12}\).*/\1`

*Explanation*:

- `%` - signals to apply search and replace on each line in a file
- `\(.\{12}\).*` - search part

  - `\(.\{12\}\).*` is a regex, `(`, `)`, `{`, `}` escaped with `\` so vim
    engine will understand that those are special signs. Without escaping it looks like this: `(.{12}).*`.
  - `(.{12})` - capturing group, match first any 12 characters
  - `.*` - any character`.` zero or more times `*`
- `\1` - replace part, it means keep only first captured group after matching.
  In our case those will be first 12 character on the line.

More thorough explanation on search and replace in vim [wiki](https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Search_and_replace#:%7E:text=Search%20for%20text%20using%20%2F%20or,to%20repeat%20the%20last%20change.)

Answer (score 0):

Use the Jeday powers (regex) of vim:

```
:%s/\d \zs.*//
```

Read more at --> `:h \zs`

```
:%norm 3whD

% ................ in the whole file
norm ............. in normal mode
3w ............... jump 3 words
h ................ move one char to the left
D ................ delete the rest of the line
```